# phonegap where is config.xml?

Tags: cordova

in my

```
src/<your package name>/<YourAppName>.java
```

I can see

```
// Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
```

so where I can find config.xml ?

I want to change 
from

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

to

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/app/index.html");
```

I found a config.xml in assets/www but I can't see

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

**BTW**

what's android_asset I don't have any folder
named like that !

### UPDATE

with this cmd

```
phonegap create mynewphonegap --id "it.mydomain.mynewphonegap" --name "MyNewOne"
```

I can find my config.xml in the route folder
with

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

thanks the same for the help :)

Comment: what device you use? android or ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `config.xml` should be in the root of your `www` folder. Be aware that this file has been introduced in PhoneGap 3.0, if you don't have one you might be using an older version. From [the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_index.md.html):

> The optional `content` element defines your application's starting
>   page in the top-level web assets directory. The default value is
>   index.html, which customarily appears in a project's top-level www
>   directory.

Comment: I can see the file but I can't see <content src="index.html" />

Comment: @Whisher Updated my answer; if it doesn't exist, simply add it.

Answer (score 1):

Right click project and select properties.

[image]

Resource > Resource Filters

Remove all in `Exclude All` except `^(build.xml|ant-gen|ant-build|custom_rules.xml|CordovaLib|platform_www|cordova)`

[image]

Click Ok.

Then go to **your_project** > **res** > **config.xml**

[image]